# Link all references for a local rename (does not change references in other files)

Tags: android

using display metrics first time having error `"Link all references for a local rename (does not change references   in other files)"` so that all lines which are having id's shows id is not resolved .here i am placing the code .help me.

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            try{
                emailForConfigChanges = emailTextBox.getText().toString().trim();
                passwordForConfigChanges = passwordTextBox.getText().toString().trim();

                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                switch(displayMetrics.densityDpi){ 
                    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                        setContentView(R.layout.login_small);
*showing error in the above line "Link all references for a local rename (does not change references   in other files)"*

                        break; 
                    default:
                        setContentView(R.layout.login);
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            ImageButton loginButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
            loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            ImageButton registerOrangeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.registerOrangeButton);
            registerOrangeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            TextView forgotPasswordText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forgotPasswordText);
            forgotPasswordText.setOnClickListener(this);

            passwordTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordLogin);
            passwordTextBox.setText(passwordForConfigChanges);
            passwordTextBox.setOnKeyListener(this);
            emailTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
            emailTextBox.setText(emailForConfigChanges);
            emailTextBox.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check import section

if this line --> "import android.R;" exist you should remove

[image]